# Rebind ng-model to service object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have a view which contains a ng-model which connect a null service object at first. As the object is null the ng-model is not bind to this value even when the value is available. Is there any way that I can rebind ng-model to the value available. I don't want to use ng-change as ng-change just trigger the one way binding. 
Here is the plunker.

http://plnkr.co/edit/4jILPHJy2P6ueIaJSlNl?p=preview

In the plunker, there's a service 'myService' in formController. And in the html, I bind the ng-model with the variable inside service myService.name.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" ng-model="myService.name">
```

What I want to do is when I click the button, as the service name is initialized so I can bind the ng-model with the service variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original code, myService is not in the $scope of ng controller. So, even you bind input with myService.name, the ng-model is not the myService you created.

You have to assign myService to $scope as below to make your code work.

```
var formApp = angular.module('formApp', [])


.service('myService',function(){
   this.name='hello';
})

.controller('formController', function($scope,myService) {

    // we will store our form data in this object
    $scope.formData = {};
    $scope.myService = myService;
    $scope.click=function(){
      myService.name='test';
    }

});
```

But I recommend you create a local variable in $scope and assign the value in service to it rather than get the whole service object. That is the whole purpose of ng service to provide some kind of 'service'.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But it seems to be working only by passing the whole object. If the code is as follows:
    $scope.myService.name=myService.name; 
Then it didn't work.

Comment: I think Yang Zhang meant just `$scope.name = myService.name`, with `ng-model="name"` on your input tag.

Comment: what if I've created an instance of MyService: `var _myservice = new myService()` and I want to bind it with $scope ? how do I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be, having an Init function in your service and passing your scope into your service. Then call init function at the top of your controller.  Something like in your service:

```
Init: function(scope){
      scope.myService = this;
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
.controller('formController', function($scope,myService) {    
     myService.Init($scope);    
});
```

Now you should be able to use:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" ng-model="myService.name">
```